# Extract amount with preg_match from string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, extract

I'm trying to extract the amounts from the follow string / text:

```
Offerlist: 19939 Product: Technic Time: 13.01.16 - 14:08 Delivery: txt Offer36: 0,00 EUR Offer38: 185€ Best-Offer: 0,00 Offer5: 100 Offer1: 000000 Offer34: 80,00€ Offer5443: 185€ Offer876a: 00 Best-Offer: 200
```

I have tried this:

```
if (preg_match("/(?<=Offer1:)(.*?)(?=Offer34:)/s", $output, $result)) {
  $offer = trim($result[0]);
}
```

But the problem is, if the name or position changes, the script doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Please clarify, are you just trying to get the 1st offer value `000000` or all of them?

Comment: What from that string do you want? Maybe you could just use `:\h+([\d,]+)`?

Comment: I try to get all of them. And I must can search for example for Offer1 and get the amount.

Comment: All values after the `:`s? e.g. you want `000000`, `80,00`, `185`, `00`, and `200`?

Comment: Yes if I can search after for example "Best-Offer:", "Offer876a" because in the text are also other strings.

Comment: post a reproducable example.

Comment: Offerlist: 19939 Product: Technic  Time: 13.01.16 - 14:08 Delivery: txt Offer36: 0,00 EUR Offer38: 185€ Best-Offer: 0,00 Offer5: 100 Offer1: 000000 Offer34: 80,00€ Offer5443: 185€ Offer876a: 00 Best-Offer: 200

Comment: add it to ur question.

Comment: Have changed it in the question

Comment: and the expected is?

Comment: Try [`\s*([^:]+):\s*(\S+(?:\s*-\s*\S+)?)`](https://regex101.com/r/wA5iB1/1). See [this IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/7jKH6u).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should search for the value instead of it's siblings.

So the following script should work better:

```
$dates = [];
if (preg_match_all("/(\w+\d*): (\d+(,\d+)?[€]?|\d\d\.\d\d.\d\d \- \d\d:\d\d|\w+)/s", $output, $result, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
  foreach ($result as $data) {
    $dates[] = [$data[1] => $data[2]];
  }
}
```

Comment: This version some how corrups the `€` symbols.

Comment: True, didn't tested it and but it should work if you remove the square brackets around it

Answer (score 1):

Using preg_match_all() and very explicit programming it can be done like this:

```
$string = 'Offer1: 000000 Offer34: 80,00€ Offer5443: 185€ Offer876a: 00 Best-Offer: 200';

$regex = '/((best-)?offer[^:]*:)([ 0-9,€]+)/i';

preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);

$offers = [];
for($c = 0; $c < count($matches[1]); $c++) {
  $label = substr($matches[1][$c],0,-1);
  $offers[$label] = trim($matches[3][$c]);
}

var_dump($offers);
```

Output:

```
array(5) {
  ["Offer1"]=>
  string(6) "000000"
  ["Offer34"]=>
  string(8) "80,00€"
  ["Offer5443"]=>
  string(6) "185€"
  ["Offer876a"]=>
  string(2) "00"
  ["Best-Offer"]=>
  string(3) "200"
}
```

Live example can be found at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/549db3d4d797e5821ede99612b18ac24d19ce9e8

Comment: What I must change if I want to have all value with ":"? Also Time, Product?